# AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "module.path" "write")

Tags: java

I am trying to configure the JBoss server to run under the java security manager using:`set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%  -Djava.security.manager "`
in `JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf.bat file`. But when I run `JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.bat` to start the server, it is giving me the following error:

```
java.security.policy: error adding Entry: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: vfs
java.security.policy: error adding Entry: java.net.MalformedURLException:  unknown protocol: vfs
Exception in thread "main" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "module.path" "write")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.System.setProperty(System.java:783)
at org.jboss.modules.main.main(Main.java:148)
```

Please let me know what I can do to configure the java security manager in JBoss.

Comment: And what is the question that we could help ?

Comment: Why do people think their log4j misconfiguration messages are relevant to other problems?

Comment: If you want help with your code, a good start would be to show us your code.

Comment: Please make more of an effort to see that your post is properly formatted.

Answer (score 5):

You need to define permissions here. To solve this startup issue, you can provide the AccessController with some information on your permissions. A simple way is to initially grant all permissions by using the allPermission directive in a separate policy file.

1. Create a file in *jboss/bin/* called *server.policy* with following content:

   `grant {
     permission java.security.AllPermission;
   };`
2. Add parameter to your JAVA_OPTS in standalone.conf.bat

   `-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/server.policy`

Now you have defined your access permissions and the server should start up.

Answer (score 1):

As my knowledge when you run your java app under security manager all the security permission are denied. So you have to mention all the security permissions manually need to be granted.

According to the exception your app does not have permission to write to module.path

[how to security-manager in jboss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/security-manager-howto.html)

Comment: Correct, but I am looking for a solution to give access to module.path to write. But can anyone please let me know if there is any harm in security perspective if I do that.